# Node url alias pattern based on taxonomy not working properly

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, 9

I have taxonomy named Category with two terms: News and Articles.

Articles term has custom url alias - `/useful`.

The website was upgaded from D7 to D9. On old D7 version node url pattern was `[node:field_categories]/[node:title]`

On D9 it is the same pattern, BUT instead of `/useful/node-title` it dispalays `/articles/node-title`

Maybe it is not a big deal, but after porting to D9 I would like to maintain current URL structure without changing it radically.

I've tried some other tokens, for example `[node:field_categories:entity:url]`, but it displays absolute path to term with domain and https after slash like `site.com/https://site.com/taxonomy-alias` which is incorrect.

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the token is the same?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. Moreover. tried all other available tokens without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found an answer!

The correct token for D8/9 is `[node:field_categories:entity:url:path]`

I don't know why, but it is not listed in available tokens.